# How to fix %2520?

Tags: url-rewriting, get

I have created a website. All links in my website are correct.

But if I come from Google index to my website, he set a %2520 in the URL instead of %20. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: what's the url in question?

Answer (score 1):

Double check the links that actually show up in HTML.  It looks like '%20' is getting escaped again to '%2520' (the hex value of '%' is 25.)

Edit: it may also be that Google scraped your website when the links were incorrect and it simply hasn't been updated on their end yet.  The solution to that is probably to wait for Google to crawl your site again.

Comment: If i go to the page in my website the page works. but if i go from google index to the same page he doesn't because of the %2520

Comment: okeej but i get a item from the database that i set in the url as a get and i use a htaccess maybe that is the problem?

Comment: for instance title: Ay Bekasoo ke Wali De Hamary Sahara from google index https://www.google.nl/#hl=nl&safe=off&sclient=psy-ab&q=Ay+Bekasoo+ke+Wali+De+Hamary+Sahara+nasheed&oq=Ay+Bekasoo+ke+Wali+De+Hamary+Sahara+nasheed&gs_l=serp.3...9200.12660.0.13051.2.2.0.0.0.0.135.167.1j1.2.0...0.0...1c.1.5.psy-ab.CwdEY6I_qkU&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=2fb392da4452c160&biw=1920&bih=936 my website www.naatnasheed.com from my website http://naatnasheed.com/naats?letter=1&page=1

Comment: You should expose the URL to Google with the spaces and let each user's browser handle the ' ' => '%20' conversion.  Invalid URL characters are automatically translated by Google and/or the user's browser, so I would suggest exposing your URLs with the spaces in them.

Comment: You mean %20 in url of just normal spaces?